# Why am I getting error :- Invalid image "2022-datacenter-g2"

Tags: azure, powershell, command-line-interface

I dont know why I keep getting the error "Invalid image "2022-datacenter-g2". Use a valid image URN, custom image name, custom image id, VHD blob URI, or pick an image from..."

I listed the images using the cli command below :

```
az vm image list-skus -l westeurope -f WindowsServer -p  MicrosoftWindowsServer
```

I got the image name from the above which was 2022-datacenter-g2, I then used this in my code $(imagename) contains "2022-datacenter-g2"  (--image $(imagename) )

az vm create --name $(vmname) --resource-group $vmrsgname --admin-username $(adminusername) --admin-password $(adminpassword) --image $(imagename) --nics $(nicname)  --os-disk-name $(osdiskname) --os-disk-size-gb $(osdisksize) --storage-sku $(storagesku) --size $(vmsize) --computer-name $(computername) --license-type Windows_Server

Answer (score 0):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got the results like below:***

I executed the **`az vm image list-skus`** command:

[image]

To create Azure VM with **`2022-datacenter-g2`** image, I executed the below command and got the **same error**:

```
az vm create --name testvm --resource-group Rukmini --image 2022-datacenter-g2
```

[image]

To resolve the error, I tried to create the Azure VM with **`Win2022AzureEditionCore`** image like below:

```
az vm create --resource-group Rukmini --name testvmruk --image Win2022AzureEditionCore --location westeurope
```

***The Azure VM got created successfully with 2022-datacenter-g2 and in West Europe location like below:***

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue and found out that specifying the entire pathn works in Powershell like below.
*PublisherName:Offer:Skus:Version*

Example:

```
$ImageName = 'MicrosoftWindowsServer:WindowsServer:2022-Datacenter-g2:Latest'
```